# Convert list into DataFrame in R? Error: Gets default column names(x1, x2, x3..) instead of the names from the list

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert around 200 lines of json strings into dataframe in R. I end up getting default column names in the data frame instead of the ones mentioned in the list. Here is my code:

```
 out <- lapply(readLines("exampleFile.json", n=200), fromJSON) // Used to convert json into a list
 test <- data.frame(t(sapply(out,c))) //convert the list into a dataframe
```

Attached is the sceenshot of the results of the variables 'out' [image]

Attached is the sceenshot of the results of the variables 'test'
[image]

Anyhelp is appreciated!

Comment: can you post `dput(lapply(out[1:4], head))` ?

Comment: list(list(banner_id = 261, bid_id = "1551", 
    bid_price = 0.03, browser = "Chrome", campaign_id = 33L, 
    city = "Raa"), 
list(banner_id = 26L, bid_id = "155", 
    bid_price = 0.037, browser = "Chrome", campaign_id = 3395L, 
    city = "Ein"), l
list(banner_id = 26, bid_id = "1", 
    bid_price = 0.03, browser = "Safari", campaign_id = 33, 
    city = "Hee"), 
list(banner_id = -1L, bid_id = "1551", 
    bid_price = 0, browser = "Chrome", campaign_id = -1L, city = "Eng"))

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)`

Comment: It says:  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length

Comment: If you have unequal length , Try `data.table::rbindlist(out, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: It did work! Thank you. Can you please post this as an answer, so that I can accept it!

Comment: Thanks, however this has been asked before so I marked it as duplicate of that post. Hope that is fine.